# Tkinter <Return> event binding is not working in python script

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Thank you for your time to answer the question. I am a beginner at scripting so I am not too familiar with GUI principles.

I am writing a script involving tkinter to search and print information from wolframalpha and wikipedia based on user's text input and hitting the  key.

```
class citrus(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tkinter   .Tk.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.initialize()
    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.entry.bind = ("<Return>", self.OnEnter)
        self.entry.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.resizable(True, True)
 def OnEnter(self, event):
        input = self.entryVariable.get()
        input = input.lower
        try:
            appID = "ER92YJ-GAXAJEPXEK"
            client = wolf.Client(appID)
            res = client.query(input)
            answer = next(res.results).text
            print(answer)
        except:
            wikipedia.set_lang("en")
            print(wikipedia.summary(input, sentences=3))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = citrus(None)
    app.title("citrus")
    app.mainloop()
```

For some reason the GUI window that shows up would not do anything after a user input texts into the text box and hits the key whereas it's supposed to give information gathered from wolframalpha or wikipedia.

I would be grateful for explanations of the reason why the script failed.

Comment: The indentation in your code example is broken. `def OnEnter` is not indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining `bind` rather than calling it.

The problem is the `=` in this line of code:

```
self.entry.bind = ("<Return>", self.OnEnter)
```

The code should be this instead:

```
self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnEnter)
```